# How do I create a space between Bootstrap buttons and table

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: Bootstrap spacing between buttons and table]

I've only just learnt Bootstrap. I'm to keep my code clean and simple, and would like to keep to best practices. I'm trying to create a space between the buttons and the table, because at the moment the buttons are right up against the top of the table and it doesn't look good. I've tried using mb1 and pb1 but nothings working.

```
<!-- Show Expenses Card -->
<div class="card mt-4">
    <div class="card-header">
    Expense {{id}}
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        {% if not data_integrity %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                This expense has data Integrity issues!
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class='mb2'><!-- mb2 is for spacing and isn't work. Pls fix. -->
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Update</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Delete</a>
        </div>

        <table class="table mt2"><!-- mt2 is for spacing and isn't work. Pls fix. -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Date</th>
                    <td>{{journal_entry.date}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Account</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.1.ledger }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Expense</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.ledger }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Project</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.project }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Store</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.1.description }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Description</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.description }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Amount</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.dr }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Created by</th>
                    <td>{{ journal_entry.user }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">Data Integrity</th>
                    <td>{{ data_integrity }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are different techniques. Simply add a div element with some points height like `<div style="height: 10px"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The class you want is "mb-2", not "mb2". 
See this bootstap guide https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 0):

First solution would be to add margin to some of them, Update - right margin, or Delete - left margin. For example:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary mr-4" href="#" role="button">Update</a>
```

Many other solutions are available, including inserting the additional element, abusing &nbsp and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-` in the class name - `mb-2`. And in general magrins are the way to go, `mb-1` is a very small margin (assuming you didn't change any default bootstrap variables). To see changes I would go with bigger values in order to be able to identify them on the page, something like `mb-3` or `mb-5`.